# send tweets using TweetSharp

Tags: c#, send, tweets, tweetsharp

Currently, I  have to post a Tweets (messages ) to the Twitter account. Im using  TweetSharp 2.3.1.

Following is my code :

```
var  service = new TwitterService(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
service.AuthenticateWith(Token, TokenSecret);
TwitterStatus result = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions
{
    Status = "Hello, world!"
});
```

But, Every time  Im getting errror: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.  Though my credentials correct  but  gettting above error while posting.

Kindly, assist me if anyone knows...

Comment: did you check **that you have Read, write, and direct messages access level** and finally working ? not marked answer ? For me not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that you have **Read, write, and direct messages access level**.

If not then change access level into Read,write and direct message and **re-create access token**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TweetSharp is not being maintained anymore. It has lots of issues with Twitter API 1.1 and you may expect several exceptions while using it. I suggest you try to install **TweetSharp-Unofficial** version insted of Tweetsharp then try to run your application. I faced similar issues with TweetSharp and that solution fixed all my issues.